# MySQLI PHP query failing

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

//Sorry for the bad English.

I'm working on a blog script and it's not working out so 'good' as I expected it to be.
I'm getting the error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: mysqli_result::$fetch_array
```

Now I know that it means that my MySQLI query is returning NULL or false to me, but I runned my query into PHPMyAdmin to see if it's wrong, but it works in there.

I've tried debugging it by using var_dump etc. but I'm stuck for one hour right now, hope that you guys can help me. My code:

```
    <?php
include_once "header.php";

$queryInfo       = "SELECT id,datum,auteur,comments,tags,titel,omschrijving,image FROM blog ORDER BY datum DESC";
$selectqInfo     = $mysqli->query($queryInfo);
?>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="sixteen columns">
                <div class="breadcrumb">
                    <a href="home" class="first_bc"><span>Home</span></a>
                    <a href="blog" class="last_bc"><span>Blog</span></a>
                </div>
                <div class="page_heading"><h1>Blog</h1></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <!-- Wide Column -->
            <div class="twelve columns">
            <?php
            $stringBlog = array();
            while($stringBlog = $selectqInfo->fetch_array);
            {
            ?>
                <div class="post_item">
                    <div class="pic">
                        <a href="blog_item.html"><img src="<?php $stringBlog['image']; ?>"/><div class="img_overlay"></div></a>
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="post_title"><a href="blog_item.html"><?php $stringBlog['titel']; ?></a></h3>
                    <p class="post_meta">
                        <span class="calendar"><a href="blog.html"><?php $stringBlog['datum']; ?></a></span>
                        <span class="author"><a href="blog.html"><?php $stringBlog['auteur']; ?></a></span>
                        <span class="comments"><a href="blog_item.html"><?php $stringBlog['comments']; ?> reacties</a></span>
                        <span class="tags"><a href=""><?php $stringBlog['tags']; ?></a></span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="post_description"><?php $stringBlog['omschrijving']; ?></p>                   
                </div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
                <div class="post_item">
                    <div class="pic">
                        <a href="blog_item.html"><img src="images/blog_img2_700.jpg"/><div class="img_overlay"></div></a>
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="post_title"><a href="blog_item.html">Clean and Modern</a></h3>
                    <p class="post_meta">
                        <span class="calendar"><a href="">24 September, 2012</a></span>
                        <span class="author"><a href="">by Admin</a></span>
                        <span class="comments"><a href="">3 Comments</a></span>
                        <span class="tags"><a href="">Web Design</a>, <a href="">Web Development</a></span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="post_description"><?php var_dump($queryInfo, $selectqInfo, $stringBlog); ?>.</p>                  
                </div>
```

//The text is in Dutch, and de value of the var_dump is:

```
string(91) "SELECT id,datum,auteur,comments,tags,titel,omschrijving,image FROM blog ORDER BY datum DESC" object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(8) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(2) ["type"]=> int(0) } NULL
```

Comment: please update your code snippet with the fixes so far so that we can better analyze where you are in your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
while($stringBlog = $selectqInfo->fetch_array()) {
    ...
}
```

You need to call the function `fetch_array` using `()` and you must not put the semicolon there.

---

**Update:** You need to `echo` the variables:

```
while($stringBlog = $selectqInfo->fetch_array()) {
?>
    <div class="post_item">
        <div class="pic">
            <a href="blog_item.html"><img src="<?php echo $stringBlog['image']; ?>"/><div class="img_overlay"></div></a>
        </div>
        <h3 class="post_title"><a href="blog_item.html"><?php echo echo $stringBlog['titel']; ?></a></h3>
        <p class="post_meta">
            <span class="calendar"><a href="blog.html"><?php echo $stringBlog['datum']; ?></a></span>
            <span class="author"><a href="blog.html"><?php echo $stringBlog['auteur']; ?></a></span>
            <span class="comments"><a href="blog_item.html"><?php echo $stringBlog['comments']; ?> reacties</a></span>
            <span class="tags"><a href=""><?php echo $stringBlog['tags']; ?></a></span>
        </p>
        <p class="post_description"><?php echo $stringBlog['omschrijving']; ?></p>                   
    </div>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Thank you but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

fetch_array is a function, not a var so it should have '()' appended to it in the while loop.

That might be why you are getting an undefined property rather than a method.

ex:

```
while($stringBlog = $selectqInfo->fetch_array)
```

might need to be

```
while($stringBlog = $selectqInfo->fetch_array())
```

Comment: The Notice error is gone, but the while loop is still not working. Thank you for trying.

Comment: @user2975129 Remove the `;` at the end of that line.

Comment: can you get a num_row_return from your mysqli object? Can you tell whether you actually have anything resulting from your query to be fetched?

Comment: If I'm adding num_rows it will give me a fatal error time of 30 seconds etc. I have 2 rows of info in the SQL table, so I don't know what the problem is with that, I thought the query was failing me.